# Group by not getting the expected results in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

I have the next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    bt.name, b.id
FROM
    ports po,
    cities c,
    provinces p,
    countries co,
    states s,
    translations t,
    element_types et,    
    languages l,
    boat_models bm, 
    boat_types bt,
    boats b
        JOIN
    boat_prices bprf ON b.id = bprf.boat_id
        AND bprf.checkin_date IS NULL
        AND bprf.duration_id IS NULL
WHERE
    t.element_translation = 'España'
    AND et.name = 'Country'
    AND s.name = 'confirmed'    
    AND s.id = b.state_id
    AND l.locale = 'es'
    AND t.language_id = l.id
    AND t.element_type_id = et.id
    AND t.element_id = p.country_id        
        AND c.province_id = p.id        
        AND po.city_id = c.id
        AND b.port_id = po.id
        AND bm.id = b.boat_model_id 
        AND bt.id = bm.boat_type_id
```

That is working perfectly and returning 9 rows:

```
'BOAT_TYPE_CATAMARAN','13707'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13700'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13701'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13702'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13703'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13704'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13705'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13706'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','13708'
```

I want to group the results by boat type and get the number of boats per type.

However, when I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    bt.name, COUNT(b.id) AS num_boats
FROM
    ports po,
    cities c,
    provinces p,
    countries co,
    states s,
    translations t,
    element_types et,    
    languages l,
    boat_models bm, 
    boat_types bt,
    boats b
        JOIN
    boat_prices bprf ON b.id = bprf.boat_id
        AND bprf.checkin_date IS NULL
        AND bprf.duration_id IS NULL
WHERE
    t.element_translation = 'España'
    AND et.name = 'Country'
    AND s.name = 'confirmed'    
    AND s.id = b.state_id
    AND l.locale = 'es'
    AND t.language_id = l.id
    AND t.element_type_id = et.id
    AND t.element_id = p.country_id        
        AND c.province_id = p.id        
        AND po.city_id = c.id
        AND b.port_id = po.id
        AND bm.id = b.boat_model_id 
        AND bt.id = bm.boat_type_id 
GROUP BY bt.name
ORDER BY bt.name
```

I´m getting:

```
'BOAT_TYPE_CATAMARAN','241'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','1928'
```

but according to the first query, I´m expecting

```
'BOAT_TYPE_CATAMARAN','1'
'BOAT_TYPE_SAILBOAT','8'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For what's missing, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Apply count over your DISTINCT select, i.e. `SELECT COUNT()... FROM (SELECT DISTINCT...)`

Comment: Sorry, not sure that I understood, do you mena that I don´t need the group by? And if I just have the count, I don´t have the boat types aggregation? Could you please provide a more detailed example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT bt.name, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS num_boats
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY bt.name
ORDER BY bt.name
```

That is: move the `DISTINCT` within the `COUNT()` rather than directly in the `SELECT`.

Generally speaking, `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` do not go along well together; `DISTINCT` is already aggregation in essence, so mixing both is usually not relevant.

Note that your syntax uses old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `FROM` clause): you should be using standard joins (with the `ON` keyword), whose syntax has been state-of-the-art for decades.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a distinct in your first query so you are 'hiding' a lot if rows that gets doubled because of your join.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I don´t totally get it. If I just remove the distinct I get the same result.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?